# ETH transaction stuck perpetually pending

Tags: pending-transactions

I have a ETH Wallet on myetherwallet.com that I have sent ETH to my coinbase account successfully many times before, but my last attempt yesterday to send all of my current wallet value to my coinbase ETH doesn't seem to be working. When I go to my ETH wallet on myetherwallet and try to send from myetherwallet.com, which is address `0x19973A4e9b5d841BBb97018b39EA6f2188Dbd04b` to my coinbase ETH wallet, which is `0x5e212b287169673f37968E152c1Da68e888E61aA` it says on etherscan that it is pending, but it has been doing that for almost a full day now and nearly every time I go and check it on etherscan, I noticed the timer resets too; which seems odd to me since past transactions I've done successfully have kept a running time from when I actually started the transaction instead of resetting nearly each time I view it...

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb873a2f66e87127b3e27973c26edb0ab3524ec73b7fd618a1c0ec049f32078cf

My Google searches on this situation have been fruitless I have just not seen this happen before as every time I have done this in the past, the transaction started getting block confirmations right away and I received an email from coinbase that the transaction has started almost immediately and neither of these have happened yet this time and I'm a little concerned about this.

Any help and suggestions I could get on this would be appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: How much gas limit should put if I want to send 0.8 ether?

Answer (score 2):

The transaction's gas price is 10 gwei, which is extremely low at present. https://www.ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php predicts it will take 7 days, but I'm not sure I would expect it to ever complete. MyEtherWallet has a tool to help cancel or replace transactions with low gas. Start at https://www.myetherwallet.com/#check-tx-status and find your transaction. (You may have to pick Etherscan from the dropdown in the upper right.)

Use https://ethgasstation.info/ to guide you as to an appropriate gas price.

Comment: Ah, didn't think about that; probably because I'm still fairly new to this and didn't really understand the whole gas thing.  I'll try to cancel it later today when I get home from work and try it again with a higher gas price then.  Hopefully that will get it going.


So, I assume the "Gas Price SafeLow (Gwei)" is the lowest reccomended number that it will most likely get picked up and processed/mined at, Correct? I have always left the default myetherwallet settings and been fine, but this TX is the most ETH I have had so far.  Wonder why the default isn't higher on myetherwallet?

Comment: Yeah, or bump it up just a little bit from SafeLow (since lots of people use exactly that number). BTW, I see "Default is 20 GWEI" on https://www.myetherwallet.com/. But that's still quite low.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll do like 25 or so then. I assume the transaction can't be edited/modified?  You do actually have to cancel it first and then start another, correct?

Comment: It can't be modified, but it can be replaced by another transaction with the same nonce. (Only one of those two transactions can be accepted by the network, and the one with the higher gas price is almost certainly going to win.) "Canceling" just means replacing with a transaction that does nothing (e.g. transfers 0 ether to yourself).

Comment: So, I was looking at that calculator and was expecting it to give a recommended gas price and limit number for a certain amount of ETH, but looks like that's not what that one does.  What calculator do you guys use for getting the recommended gas price and limit for a certain amount of ETH? or is the amount of ETH in the TX not really a factor?

Comment: The amount of ether is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, thought so from what I've gathered.  I'll give this another shot with a higher gas price when I get home from work tonight.  Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: Hmm, just tried to replace the TX and got the error that there wasn't enough funds, which makes no sense because the number of ETH it shows when click on "Send Entire Balance" is correct, so I don't know what it is talking about and my gas price is actually defaulted to 10 on myether wallet.com for some reason, but just changed it to 25.  Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Comment: Make sure to click "Send Entire Balance" again after adjusting the gas price. (It doesn't automatically recalculate, so if you increase the gas price, you no longer have enough ether left behind to pay for the transaction.)

Comment: Just tried that too and it is not changing the gas price after I select a gas price value and click send "Send Entire Balance" again and it also doesn't let me manually change it in the gas price field either.  I even closed out of all the windows in each browser and tried again, still no go. I even tried both Chrome and Firefox with the same result and error message.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you be specific about what's not working here? The gas price is changed via a dropdown and slider in the upper right part of the website. Are you saying you're moving the slider but the price isn't being updated? Or something else?

Comment: Correct, slider bar changes the gas price at the top of the page, but doesn't update the gas price field in the TX details even after clicking on "Send Entire Balance" again afterwards.

Comment: Are you maybe confusing the gas price with the gas limit? The gas limit does not change when you change the gas price, and I don't see the gas price anywhere in the transaction details.

Comment: But hopefully the "amount to send" changes when you click "Send Entire Balance" after adjusting the gas price.

Comment: Nope, I'm only looking at the gas price sections and the price  and ETH amount does not change when I click "Send Entire Balance" after adjusting the gas price unfortunately. What browser do you use when doing this?

Comment: Chrome. To clarify, the URL I'm on is https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction. I'm unclear on what you mean when you say "the price." Could you share a screenshot or at least say exactly what field you're looking at? All I see is "To Address," "Amount to Send," and "Gas Limit." The gas price is displayed in the header, and it changes immediately as I move the slider.

Comment: Yep, that is the page I am using and what I am doing, but what "I'm saying is that when I choose a gas price with the slider and then click "Send Entire Balance", neither the gas price or the ETH value changes in those fields at all.

Comment: So, the issue for me is that the gas price is just plain stuck at a certain number, in this case 41, so to allow it go through, I had to set the gas price on top of the page also to 41 to match it; then it went through, but that is more than I wanted and it is not changeable for me, so there is still some issue going on that I can't seem to fix, but this is ok for now.  Thanks again for the help today!

Comment: To match what? For me, the gas price is *only* at the top of the page. If you could share a screenshot or at least describe the other place you saw the gas price, that would help enormously.